Empty date error : No columns to parse from file though it looks a perfect csv file
Thank you for reading this question.
I'm a quite beginner who just started learning python.
I tried to read csv file on jupyter-notebook as following and got [No columns to parse from file] error as attached.
But CSV looks perfect...
I asked various AI how I solve and tried all of advices, but still can't solve this.
It would be appreciated if you give me some advices.
Code:
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('KvsT.csv')
df.head(3)

Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EmptyDataError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 2
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 df=pd.read_csv('KvsT.csv')
      3 df.head(3)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1026, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, date_format, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options, dtype_backend)
   1013 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
   1014     dialect,
   1015     delimiter,
   (...)
   1022     dtype_backend=dtype_backend,
   1023 )
   1024 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
-> 1026 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:620, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    617 _validate_names(kwds.get("names", None))
    619 # Create the parser.
--> 620 parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    622 if chunksize or iterator:
    623     return parser

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1620, in TextFileReader.__init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
   1617     self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
   1619 self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
-> 1620 self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1898, in TextFileReader._make_engine(self, f, engine)
   1895     raise ValueError(msg)
   1897 try:
-> 1898     return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
   1899 except Exception:
   1900     if self.handles is not None:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py:93, in CParserWrapper.__init__(self, src, **kwds)
     90 if kwds["dtype_backend"] == "pyarrow":
     91     # Fail here loudly instead of in cython after reading
     92     import_optional_dependency("pyarrow")
---> 93 self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
     95 self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
     97 # error: Cannot determine type of 'names'

File parsers.pyx:581, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Screen shot on jupyternote:
The screen snipped
How the csv file KvsT.csv looks:
身長,体重,年代,派閥
170,60,10,きのこ
172,65,20,きのこ
170,60,30,たけのこ
170,65,40,きのこ
177,65,10,たけのこ
168,55,20,きのこ
169,65,30,たけのこ
170,62,40,たけのこ
180,70,10,たけのこ
170,68,20,きのこ
165,65,40,たけのこ
170,72,20,きのこ
175,77,40,たけのこ
170,65,30,たけのこ
170,65,30,たけのこ
155,56,20,きのこ
160,56,20,たけのこ
170,65,40,きのこ
175,60,20,たけのこ


As provided, this is not reproducible. Code you provide and text content of  KvsT.csv works to display dataframe start of four columns with three rows. You can test in a fresh context by going to here and pressing launch binder and doing the steps. Did you try restarting your session and making a new CSV file? Do other .csv files work?

I can only reproduce the exact error if the .csv file is empty.  Are you sure the file was saved?  Try print(os.getcwd()) and make sure the file in that specific directory is not empty.

Hi guys, thanks for all your comments. As you point out, it seems that the file changed to empty when I dropped it on the left file space on jupyter-notebook.
Then I put the file in the same directory not on  jupyter-notebook but through explorer, it worked. I don't know why it happen but issue solved. Thanks a lot!

You could try specifiyng the encoding:
df = pd.read_csv('KvsT.csv', encoding='utf-8')

or
df = pd.read_csv('KvsT.csv', encoding='shift-jis')

If that doesnt help try to open the file to check if its broken:
with open('KvsT.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    print(file.read())

Another issue could be that the jupyter notebook runs in diferent directory
where exists empty copy of 'KvsT.csv'
You can solve this by specifiyng the full path to your file.

Hi Aizaj. Thanks a lot!
I found out the csv file is empty.
I don't know why it happened when I drop the left space on Jupyter-notebook.
I copy and past the file on the same directory not on Jupyter-notebook but explorer, it solved quickly.
